# MOSS 2007 exporting documents using C# on XP machine

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I looked at forums and some blogs to find out my answer but could not so posting here.

We have MOSS 2007 and a library where we have documents are stored, I would like to run a client utility which runs a day and export all documents imported on that day along with metadata(Column names)

I don't want to install SharePoint server on VHD or on my development environment because I don't think that just for this cause I need to to have Dev SharePoint environment. I don't want to develop this on my development SharePoint environment and give it to my SharePoint team to deploy on server because I feel I should be able to do just on my XP machine.

As SharePoint object model is available, why I cant take missing dll from server and write a small C# utility to export documents to file system? I assume I should be able to do this with SharePoint web service but my question is can I do with SharePoint object model on my XP machine? I don't want to ask my admin to use stsadm to do required work as part of script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007 there is **no support** for client-side access to the (server) object model. You have to use web services to comply with the requirements you've presented.

Also, it is not possible to take SharePoint DLLs to a client machine without SharePoint installed, and compile—or even run—code with them. It *might* be possible to achieve compilability, but the process is tedious and makes no sense at all providing it won't *ever* run on such machine.

Comment: What is use of SharePoint object model where you can only use it on server machine? I don't know why SharePoint would design like that because I am pretty sure that webservice would not be that efficient compare to using object model directly from client machine to run. I will be exporting almost 5000 files every day and luckily I dont have to worry about time it takes but still I did not like idea that SharePoint does not come with SDK which you can install on client machine and talk to server instead of doing development on server always.

Comment: Even if it would, it would anyway involve client-server communication, which is alway less efficient than direct access. Also note that beginning with SharePoint 2010 there's CSOM — Client-side Object Model.

Comment: Thanks Tucny for direction, a followup question, I understand that CSOM is not an option for MOSS 2007. I wrote C# application consuming SharePoint webservice to upload and download data from list using CAML Query. Now some one just used word SSIS and I looked into it. Can you pelase tell me why and in which case I should use SSIS, It seems like SSIS also at end uses sharepoint webservice LISTS.asmx only to access stuff.

Comment: i want to download a sample code for this model ( web service that send and receive data to client and client-side that send and receive data to web service and then web service update them in sharepoint? is there any link to download the sample standard template?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any DLLs from SharePoint 2007 to use web services.

Getting just DLLs be painful for development - you'll be able to compile your code, but to run/debug you still need full installation of SharePoint.

Note that there is special https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ dedicated to SharePoint questions.